# Loop throughDv (change cell when h > a)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub LoopThroughDv()
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim h As Range
    Dim a As Range
    Set h = Worksheets("Ark2").Range("H2")
    Set a = Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A2")

     'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Ark2").Range("I2")

     'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

    i = 0
     'Begin our loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    For Each c In inputRange
            dvCell = c.Value
        i = i + 1
    If h > a Then
        Exit For
    End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

and when h > a i want to change h,a and dvCell to cell H3, A3, and I3 and then continue increasing until blank cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the below? The point is you have to loop the entire process until you get the blank cell. You may need to adjust the until portion a bit according to your data setup.

```
i = 2

Do

    Set h = Worksheets("Ark2").Range("H" & i)
    Set a = Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A" & i)

     'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Ark2").Range("I" & i)

     'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

    For Each c In inputRange
        dvCell = c.Value
        If h.Value > a.Value Then Exit For
    Next c

    i = i + 1

Loop Until h.Offset(1).Value = ""
```